# UI thread Handler not receiving messages prior to first Activity onCreate()

Tags: android, android-handler

I have a `Handler` on the UI thread (created using `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())`) which has a sequence of messages sent to it as soon as the application starts (specifically, after the Application class' `onCreate`). What I have noticed is that this `Handler` doesn't seem to receive messages until around the time of the `onCreate` of the very first `Activity`. Prior to that point, messages sent to it appear to be lost.

Is this because the UI thread's `Looper` is not yet ready to execute messages until the first `Activity` is visible?

---

**Supplementary information**

I'm just adding this information in relation to comments below -- it's not part of the specific question.

This `Handler` is used as part of a mechanism that allows various long-running tasks to cause progress information to appear over the current `Activity`, using my own version of Eclipse's `IProgressMonitor`.

When the application starts, a piece of initialisation work is done. This work is a long-running task which involves building data structures based on contents of a file. This piece of initialisation work *might* have to be repeated later on during use of the application, depending on user operations.

In this application I have my own implementation of `IProgressMonitor`, an idea based on the class from the Eclipse Platform API. With this, various long-running tasks in the application, including the initialisation work, can grab simply grab an `IProgressMonitor` from a manager class, and call progress update methods on it (like `done()`, `percentDone()`, and so on). If any `Activity` is visible, this causes visible progress notifications to be visible (using the Crouton library).

The actual implementation behind the IProgressMonitor uses a `Handler` to transfer the `done()`, `percentDone()` etc. updates onto the UI thread. Then, the manager class gets the updates via the `Handler` and it causes visible status updates **if** an `Activity` is visible (and has registered with the manager).

What has brought me to the above question is that when the application starts and the initialisation happens for the first time, calls on the `IProgressManager` don't seem to find their way through to the manager via the UI-Thread `Handler` until the first `Activity` is visible. This doesn't matter whatsoever from a functionality point of view because without a visible `Activity` the manager can't display anything anyway. But I am just curious about the cause.

Answer (score 0):

the messages are not "lost" as you said, they are delivered, just later. That's because even thou you have have several `Handler` object, the queue the messages are going to is just one, the `Lopper` queue. And when your activity is launch, the Android system already queue-up all the other stuff it has to do in order to show the activity to the user.

On a side note: If it's not used for any UI related stuff, DO NOT PUT IT ON THE UI THREAD! Makes sense right?

Some options, might vary depending on what they're doing exactly:

- use lazy initialisation, meaning, only init those components first time the user actively needs them.
- create a `HandlerThread` with low priority to perform those operations that are not UI related. Maybe even delay them for a couple of seconds to let the whole UI be built first, before executing any of them.

**edit based on your extra information:**

I do not advise on the approach you're taking in building this and the reason is: that's not what Handlers are for and the Android framework have its own implementations for long running tasks and how to communicate back with the currently active `Activity`

"This work is a long-running task" in Android, long running tasks, specially tasks that have nothing to do with the UI, should be delegate to a `Service` Probably you should look into a `IntentService` that automatically have a `HandlerThread` that executes long tasks in a background thread the order they are received and auto-destroy when there's nothing more to execute.

To get update information about on going tasks that are being executed on the service there're two possible approaches.

1 - more complex, but more complete approach, You `bind` the Activity to the Service and direct call methods on it like `setListener`. That involves some ServiceConnection callbacks, but also allows a close interaction between activity and Service.

2 - a simpler unidirectional approach is to have dispatch updates to the `LocalBroadcastManager` and make the activity listen to them, I'll show you a quick example below:

service code, for example to send a progress update on build data structure job

```
Intent i = new Intent(MY_APP_UPDATE);
i.putExtra("serviceType", BUILDING_DATA_STRUCTURE);
i.putExtra("updateType", ON_UPDATE);
i.putExtra("updateValue", progress_percent);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(i);
```

then on your activity you create a BroadcastReceiver inner class and onResume/onPause you listen for updates.

```
private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
   @Override public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent){

          int serviceType = intent.getIntExtra("serviceType", 0);
          int updateType = intent.getIntExtra("updateType", 0);
          int updateValue = intent.getIntExtra("updateValue", 0);

          // here you can properly handle the updates being sure that your activity isResumed
   }
}
```

then onResume/onPause you register/unregister

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter(MY_APP_UPDATE));
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
```

but all that is because I like to play inside the Framework rules and builtin features as they tend to be slightly more hassle free than re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks Budius. Detailed LogCat examination indicated that the messages were being lost, but I shall go back and inspect again. The `Handler` concerned does actually indirectly cause UI updates *if* an `Activity` is visible (though it's difficult to explain in detail in a comment). Incidentally I disagree about not putting a `Handler` on the UI thread if it's for not for UI updates. In some cases I consider the main thread appropriate to perform asynchronous notification callbacks from long-running tasks - as long as no 'work' is performed within that Handler, of course.

Comment: I agree with you, with async notifications, yes. But the wording was "This is associated with initialisation of the application" which might indicate something a bit more "work" related like DB initialisation, creation, networking log, maybe loading a disk cache. But as you said, without clear explanation of what is about, I can only make a guess based on best practices. But again, if the messages are being received after the activity `onCreate`, how come they're lost?

Comment: You're right - what I wrote was quite misleading, and in actual fact almost contradictory. I've just updated my question with very specific details about what I'm doing just in case you're interested.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, it is only the messages that were _sent_ after the onCreate that appear to go through -- the ones sent prior appear to be lost.

Comment: I've added some opinions on my answer, make sure to have a read. happy coding.

Comment: Thanks. Incidentally I already use OS components inc. `IntentService` as well as standard concurrency classes e.g. `ExecutorService`. Which I use depends on the situation. I use `IntentService` for a mission-critical file save operation; as this component reduces probability of process being killed if app is backgrounded during file save. On the other hand I use `ExecutorService` for non-critical business tasks where parallel processing is needed and there's no particular justification for using a platform component. I'd like to scope this back to the original question regarding the `Handler`.